# Show a javascript loader image while function is executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to click a button, show a loader image, execute a time-consuming function, hide the loader image.  When I attempt this, the page freezes until the entire event runs, so the loader image is never seen.

Here is a sample:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#LoadingImage').show();
    <time consuming function>
    $('#LoadingImage').hide();
});
```

How can I distinctly show the loader image, update the screen, run the function, hide the loader image?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although what you have *should* work, try doing this:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#LoadingImage').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        <time consuming function>
        $('#LoadingImage').hide();
    }, 0);
});
```

This will escape the call stack of the event.

If THAT doesn't work, then post more details as to what this mystery time consuming function is.

Comment: Same idea here, although don't you mean to put the hide() call within the setTimeout, after the time consuming code has executed?

Comment: What is the reason behind it? how it is working using setTimeout function can you please explain?

Comment: @Twix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful

Answer (score 1):

For various reasons JS has to execute on the main thread, which means that painting is blocked as long as JS is executing -- even multiprocess architectures like chrome cannot repaint a tab if that tab is executing JS.

Your only way to get painting to occur will be to split up execution of your function, or move the function onto an html5 worker thread -- and they only work on the betas of Firefox and Safari (or more generally any sufficiently recent build of webkit proper)